# Uncorrect redirect after login - Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-security, bootstrap-4

In my `Spring Boot` application I have a strange problem.

After login, my web app redirect to a JS page (`bootstrap-table.js`). This page not appears every times, but only at the first login, in the successive login we are redirect to the correct page "home.html".

In my WebApp I use: `thymeleaf` and `bootstrap4`.

This is my Security Configuration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resetpwd/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .failureUrl("/?login_error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**");
    }

}
```

I have define the **css** and **js** file in `default.html`, the login form is in the header.html:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right  ml-auto " sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">

             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" th:text="#{login}"> </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu form-wrapper">                 
                    <li>

                  <form th:action="@{/login}"  data-parsley-validate="" method="POST" class="form login" >
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" th:text="#{login}" ></div>
                    <p th:if="${loginError}" style="color: red;" th:text="#{login_unsuccessful}"></p>

                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user text-info"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name='username' placeholder="Username" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key text-info"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center" value="Login">
                    <div class="form-footer">
                        <a data-target="#modalPwd" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalPwd" id="pwdDmntct" th:text="#{pwdDimenticata}"></a><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
             </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

In the body of default I have the definition of JS.

```
<body>

    <!-- page content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav th:replace="~{/fragments/header :: header}"></nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">           

            <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /page content -->

    <script th:src="@{/js/parsley/parsley.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/parsley/it.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table-it-IT.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
        $(function () {
            if($('form').length){
                $('form').parsley().on('form:validated', function(e) {
                    if (e.validationResult) {
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                });
            }
            $('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
                $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Can anyone help me to understand this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I ran into the same problem - and there's a simple answer that worked for me: just add "/webjars/**" to the list of URIs that you're setting to permitAll() in authorizeRequests().  I guess you expected your ignoring() below in your @Configuration would have done the same thing - not sure what that is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably redirected to "bootstrap-table.js", because you are trying to access it with a logged-out user. You get redirected to the login page, and after that you get redirected back to the url you were trying to reach before login redirect.

If you want to redirect to "/home" every time the user successfully logs in, no matter what page he wanted to access before login, you should use `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)`, and not `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home")`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't redirect in js, but adding this boolean value I don't have this problem!

Comment: @Apo it's not a js redirect, you are using spring formLogin, when you submit the form (with th:action="@{/login}"), all redirects are performed by spring boot backend.

Comment: I did not like this answer, as it means users always end up going to "/home", no matter where they meant to go.

Comment: @moilejter, well, the OP wanted to redirect to "/home" on login success no matter where they meant to go. If you don't want that behavior, just don't pass the flag or pass false instead or remove defaultSuccessUrl entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Sim Dim 's answer, I wanted to **preserve the auto-redirect feature after login to the page intended before login**. So I added `js file path` to controller and redirect to a default page. for example

```
@Controller 
public HomeController {

  @GetMapping("/bootstrap.js")  //whichever file it is
  public String falseLoginRedirect(Model model) {
    return "redirect:/home"; //redirect to my preferred default
  }

}
```

Comment: This seems like a hack to get it to do a righter thing - Ii think adding "/webjars/**" to the permitAll() antMatchers at the top is a more elegant way to go.  And it worked for me :-p